# ReentrantLock as replacement for CountdownLatch

Tags: java, concurrency

I have `myCountDownLatch` (which works as expected):

```
public static void myCountDownLatch() {

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread t = new Thread(() ->
    {
        try {
            log.info("CountDownLatch: in thread..");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    });
    t.start();
    try {
        countDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.info("CountDownLatch: out thread..");
}
```

I am trying to understand the difference of `CountdownLatch` and `ReentrantLock` and tried to rewrite `myCountDownLatch` by using `ReentrantLock` instead of `CountdownLatch`:

```
public static void myRentrantLock() {

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    Thread t = new Thread(() ->
    {
        try {
            log.info("ReentrantLock: in thread..");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    lock.lock();
    t.start();
    lock.unlock();

    log.info("ReentrantLock: out thread..");
}
```

**I only want to stop the main thread as long as `Thread t` is not finished by using `ReentrantLock` instead of `CountDownLatch`.**

However, `myRentrantLock` does not behave equal to my `myCountDownLatch`. Why?

Comment: Well, they're completely different objects and you're using the lock wrong (you have only one thread locking and unlocking the lock, so there's no mutual exclusion that can happen). Expecting them to behave similarly is your biggest mistake. Perhaps read through this before writing any more code https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html (especially the one about `Lock`).

Comment: Can `myCountDownLatch` be rewritten by using `ReentrantLock` instead of `CountdownLatch` or is this not possible because `ReentrantLock` cannot lock the main thread while `Thread t ` is not finished?

Comment: Sure you can probably replicate the behaviour (at least for a CDL with 1 permit). But a `Lock` doesn't lock anything. A thread *acquires* a lock (or blocks if it's already acquired), so you're thinking the wrong way around. It's all explained in the link I gave you.

Comment: Don't use anything called "lock" or "mutex" for signalling between threads. Use those things only to _prevent_ threads from interfering with each other. Use things like `CountDownLatch` and `Semaphore` and `BlockingQueue` when you want explicit interactions between threads. Using the right classes to do the job (even when some other class could be made to work) will make it easier for other programmers to read your code and understand your intent. That, in turn, will make it more likely that other programmers will want to work with you and help you.

Comment: create a class MyCountDownLatch which has the same methods as CountDownLatch and behaves exactly as CountDownLatch. using ReentrantLock.

Comment: In your first code fragment, the created thread calls `countDownLatch.countDown();`, in other words, interacts with the `CountDownLatch`. In your second example, there is no interaction between the created thread and the `ReentrantLock`, so should not surprise that nothing meaningful happens. The main thread acquires a lock and releases it, that’s all. What effect should that have?

Comment: I only want to stop the main thread as long as `Thread t` is not finished by using `ReentrantLock` instead of `CountDownLatch`. I will accept the answer if a version with `ReentrantLock` is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not *replace* a countdown latch with a `ReentrantLock`, which is a tool for mutual exclusion and notification, but you could use a `ReentrantLock` to implement a similar functionality.

It may look like

```
public class MyLatch {
    final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition zeroReached = lock.newCondition();
    int remaining;

    MyLatch(int count) {
        if(count < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        remaining = count;
    }
    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(remaining != 0) zeroReached.await();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if(remaining == 0) return true;
            long deadLine = System.nanoTime() + unit.toNanos(timeout);
            while(remaining != 0) {
                final long remainingTime = deadLine - System.nanoTime();
                if(remainingTime <= 0) return false;
                zeroReached.await(remainingTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            }
            return true;
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void countDown() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if(remaining > 0 && --remaining == 0) zeroReached.signalAll();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public long getCount() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
          return remaining;
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ReentrantLock` guards the internal state, which is the `remaining` field. The associated `Condition zeroReached` is used to allow threads waiting for the `remaining` field to become zero.

This can be used the same way as the builtin `CountDownLatch`:

```
public class MyLatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 10;
        MyLatch countDownLatch = new MyLatch(num);
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() ->
            {
                try {
                    System.out.println("CountDownLatch: in thread..");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("CountDownLatch: one thread finished..");
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            });
            t.start();
        }
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("CountDownLatch: out thread..");
    }
}
```

Note that you don’t need an explicit `Lock` here, Java’s intrinsic locking feature would work as well:

```
public class MyLatch {
    int remaining;

    MyLatch(int count) {
        if(count < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        remaining = count;
    }
    public synchronized void await() throws InterruptedException {
        while(remaining != 0) wait();
    }
    public synchronized boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        if(remaining == 0) return true;
        long deadLine = System.nanoTime() + unit.toNanos(timeout);
        while(remaining != 0) {
            long remainingTime = deadLine - System.nanoTime();
            if(remainingTime <= 0) return false;
            wait(remainingTime / 1_000_000, (int)(remainingTime % 1_000_000));
        }
        return true;
    }
    public synchronized void countDown() {
        if(remaining > 0 && --remaining == 0) notifyAll();
    }
    public synchronized long getCount() {
        return remaining;
    }
}
```

But in either case, the builtin `CountDownLatch` is more efficient…